# Xcode code folding case statements

Tags: xcode, case

Is there a way to make the case statements in a switch be folded?

I am using the Xcode 4.5.2

Comment: Development related questions including Xcode should be on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your cases with { }. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks bogdanscr, but is there a way to do it without the curly braces?